# outputs of different list comprehensions in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, generator, list-comprehension

I was studying about list comprehension in Python and I am confused why this two codes are producing different outputs.
CODE:

```
print([(letter,num) for letter in 'abc' for num in range(2)])
print([((letter,num) for letter in 'abc') for num in range(2)])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[('a', 0), ('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 0), ('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 0), ('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 0), ('d', 1), ('d', 2), ('d', 3)]

[<generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x000002919E020F20>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x000002919E148C10>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x000002919E1489E0>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x000002919E148C80>]
```

Comment: I think it is obvious from the placements of extra parentheses, but the first one is a nested list comprehension while the second is a generator expression inside a list comprehension.

Comment: Did you expect the parenthesis to perform some type of order of operations?

Answer (score 1):

The first example:

```
print([(letter,num) for letter in 'abc' for num in range(2)])
```

Prints a list (because of the outer `[]` brackets) which contains all the tuples (because of the parentheses around `letter, num`) of `letter` and `num` for each value of `letter` looping over `'abc'` and each value of `num` looping over every value of the generator returned by `range(2)` (which will be `0` and `1`).

Since Python takes the first `for` as the outer loop, you see `('a', 0), ('a', 1),` etc. instead of `('a', 0), ('b', 0),` etc.

However, when you add parentheses around a `for` expression like `(letter,num) for letter in 'abc'`, you're no longer executing the loop in the comprehension, but you're capturing the generators (ready to start yielding their values, but not actually yielding the values into the comprehension).

So:

```
print([((letter,num) for letter in 'abc') for num in range(2)])
```

Here, `((letter,num) for letter in 'abc')` is just a generator that will yield values as soon as you start asking for them.

Note: because the value of `num` is not enclosed in the generators separately, if you do something with them, you may see a surprising result:

```
x = [((letter,num) for letter in 'abc') for num in range(2)]
print(next(x[0]))
print(next(x[0]))
print(next(x[0]))
print(next(x[1]))
print(next(x[1]))
print(next(x[1]))
```

Result:

```
('a', 1)
('b', 1)
('c', 1)
('a', 1)
('b', 1)
('c', 1)
```

Comment: gotcha! thanks for the explaination man. @Grismar

Answer (score 0):

The first list comprehension is equivalent to nested loops:

```
result = []
for num in range(2):
    for letter in 'abc':
        result.append((letter, num))
print(result)
```

Each iteration of the nested loop produces in an element of the resulting list.

The second is equivalent to a single loop:

```
result = []
for num in range(2):
    result.append((letter, num) for letter in 'abc')
print(result)
```

Each iteration of the loop appends a generator object to the resulting list.

You could use a nested list comprehension, but then the result will be nested lists, not a flat list as in the first version.

```
print([list((letter,num) for letter in 'abc') for num in range(2)])
# output: [[('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 0)], [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)]]
```